# PHP: Convert monday in this timezone to UTC

Tags: php, date, time, timestamp

I am building an App that fetches all entries a user has made "this week" (in their timezone). I store all entry times in the database as UTC/GMT time using:

```
gmdate('U')
```

My problem arises when I need to fetch "this week" in their timezone. Before i took timezones into account i used...

```
$startWeek = strtotime('monday this week 00:00')
$endWeek = strtotime('sunday this week 00:00')
```

...and used a SQL statement that searched BETWEEN those two variables.

The problem is, those two variables are using the server times, so it gives the servers start and end of the week.

I have access to the users timezone (ie: Australia/Melbourne) in a cookie if needed.

Bottom line, how do I fetch the beginning and end of the week, in timestamp format, in the timezone i have stored in a cookie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `date_default_timezone_set` function fits your requirement:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

You need to get the timezone from the user and then call the function with it. Going from the timezone, the following snippet should work:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Melbourne/Australia');
```

Comment: So when i fetch results from the database (which contains UTC times) then the following is relevant...
`
    date_default_timezone_set(get_cookie('userTimezone'));
    $startWeek = gmdate('U', strtotime('monday this week 00:00'));
    $endWeek = gmdate('U', strtotime('sunday this week 23:59'));
`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a halfway current PHP installation, this'll do it:

```
$usersTimezone = new DateTimeZone($timezone); // e.g. "Australia/Melbourne"
$time = new DateTime('monday this week 00:00', $usersTimezone);

$serversTimezone = new DateTimeZone('Servers Timezone'); // e.g. "UTC"
$time->setTimezone($serversTimezone);

$sqlTime = $time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```